# Edit list to join characters

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
```

I would like to transform the list into this:

```
l = ['abc']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that second thing supposed to be `['abc']`, i,e. a list containing a single string?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: So where is your attempt to implement this, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
l = ['a','b','c'] 
l = ["".join(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to become `l=['abc']` you could do something like

```
l=[''.join( l ) ]
```